# How to deactivate the IOs fullscreen mode for html5 video tag

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I'm trying to disable the iPhone's automatic full screen mode for the html5 video tag. And I found a bunch of answers that mention the "playsInline" solution. However, nothing changes for me when I put "playsInline" in my video tag. What am I doing wrong?

```
         <video
            playsInline
            id="video"
           
          >
            <source src={props.video} />
            Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
         </video>
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the video source as attribute inside of the video-tag instead of using the source-tag:

```
     <video
        playsInline
        id="video"
        src={props.video}
      >
        Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
     </video>
```